# How to perform non-idempotent actions (send email) in a Actor model framework (e.g., akka.net)?

Tags: akka, actor, akka.net

I am looking into using an actor model framework (akka.net with akka.net persistence, but I am looking for a general case answer) to build an 'widget order processing workflow'.

Pretty standard:

1. Customer orders widget
2. Payment is processed
3. Email confirmation sent to  customer
4. Send picklist message to warehouse
5. Warehouse sends a 'widget has been shipped' message back
6. Send a 'your item has shipped' email to customer

Now let's say between 4 and 5 a server deployment/restart happens. This would cause a actor(s) rehydration (let's assume there is no snapshot yet). That means we would process the payment again, and resend the order placed email. However it turns out our customers don't like this 'feature'!

**How to I prevent non-idempotent actions from re-occurring when using an actor model framework?**

*I have thought about having a separate store of 'payment processed for order db table'; but this feels like I am fighting the framework/paradigm and I wonder if there is a 'proper' way of doing this kind of thing!*

Answer (score 0):

Ok so it turns out it is pretty simple.

With akka.net persistence, after a system restore, messages are replayed. The correct state can be recreated by (re) processing these messages.

There is however a `IsRestoring` property, which can be checked to see if this is the first or a subsequent processing. Presumably other actor model framework have something similar.

So you do something like:

```
private void ProcessPayment (Order message)
{
    if(!this.IsRestoring){
        //Perform non-idempotent payment process
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

To make a robust workflow processor, you have to store ALL data of a workflow process in a permanent storage.

You can employ a database, a messaging system like Kafka, or use ready-made workflow management software.

Since you already use Akka, [Akka Persistence](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.5/persistence.html)  also can be an option.

UPDATE

Building a system which continue to work correctly in presence of system failures and restarts is a considerable task, far more complex than developing an actor framework. That is, you cannot just take any actor framework and add fault tolerance to it.

Comment: Good info thanks, However you don't seem to be discussing anything specific to 'actor model frameworks' Do you think you could perhaps expand on your answer with that in mind?